# Is it safe to store a local declared object in a global QList?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

I got a CPP program where i make a local object A and want to store it in global object B which is a QList.

Is it save to statically allocate object A or do i need to use the **new** keyword.
Does QList uses the copy constructor?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QList stores copies of objects, so it should work. However make sure that copying is indeed what you want. If this isn't the case, allocate your object with `new` and store the pointer in the QList.

Answer (score 0):

No. Inner scope variables should not be stored in outer scoped variables. You can store the values, but not the reference/pointer to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

QList has only a pointer to it's contents. So whenever you make a copy of a QList it doesn't actually copy all of the contents, it just copies the pointer. Whenever you modify a list, a copy is made to ensure that it's not modifying the contents of other objects. See this: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qshareddatapointer.html

QList does use the copy contructor, so if your objects contain a lot of data, it might be not good to use straight objects in the QList, since copying can cause some overhead when the list needs to grow.

Another solution would be to use QSharedDataPointer to create functionality similar to that of the QList.

Note that most of Qt classes already use this, so if you class contains things listed here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/implicit-sharing.html It's somewhat unnecessary to use the QSharedDataPointer.

There is one thing that you didn't make clear that has of relevance, I think. Do you want the global static object A to have the same data as the object on the list?

This is achieveable by using either pointers or QExplicitlySharedDataPointer.

QExplicitlySharedDataPointer is much the same as QSharedDataPointer, with one exception.
It doesn't make a copy of the data when it's modified. Here's some documentation http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qexplicitlyshareddatapointer.html

I'v used those classes a lot and I'v found them very useful and not hard at all to use.

Answer (score -2):

nope. QList stores the list of pointers to objects, so local variables should not be stored in the global QList.

check out this link for details:

http://twl.pl/jtz/Inne/QT-Tutorial/qlist.html#details

Comment: That's vastly outdated. That QList is completely different from today's QList. This is the current QList, in Qt4: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlist.html . A QList<A> stores copies of A objects, a QList<A*> pointers of A objects. Storing copies where possible is recommended and safe in this scenario.